# Issue about "please make sure the application for the project (.wip) is installed"

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, vb6

I have a very old plug-in software developed in Visual Basic quite years ago, now its getting time to modify the copyright info. At this point, the issue is now that I was not the author so I don't know anything about it.

I have updated the source files which includes a SLN, VBP, WIP, MSI and so on, then I tried to use VS2008 to open the SLN file and after Conversion it given me a message "The project for XXX.wip is not installed, please make sure the application for the project (.wip) is installed", Apparently this is not right version to get going on.

Can everybody tell which VS version can proceed it? or any idea how I do this?

Comment: Kind of over-tagged there, this has nothing to do with .Net.  Copyright normally belongs to the author, so even if you paid for the work I don't think it's right to try to stick your name in there as the Copyright holder.

Comment: No, this is commercial software belongs to my company, I have taken over the responsibility here need the year of copyright to be updated. so I want to know how I can edit this old program by using which VS version? I am not familiar with .NET or VB programming.

Comment: The tags are quite right for some of our fellow programmers who know little about the differences between VB6 and VB.Net

Comment: Yes, exactly, thanks. so the program was a B VB6 program? I can only use Visual Studio 6.0 (98) to edit the source file and re-assemble msi install file?

Comment: Hmm, I was sure the original text said this was a VB6 program.  Oh well, rewriting history is what SO is all about!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need VB6 to work on a VB6 program.  Visual Studio 6.0 (98) contains the tools required.

Comment: Sorry about my lack of the knowledge， Is Visual Studio 6.0 (98) much older version than VS 2003?

Comment: @JammyC.c yes it is and to make it worse for you: the only similarity between them is their name. VS 6 and VS.Net and later address different frameworks.

Comment: Thanks, which basically says I can only use Visual Studio 6.0 (98) to edit and re-assemble .msi file? no another way?

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like the setup is built using the obsoleted [Visual Studio Installer](http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Article/19893) that is an addon application to Visual Studio for creating (VERY simplistic) MSI packages.

As it doesn't seem to be available any more, alrternatives are [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php), [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/), or ClickOnce integrated into new versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: VSI 1.1 is still perfectly functional and is one of the few packagers with actual "easy VB6" support in it.  Inno Setup is extremely hazardous in the wrong hands, and I'm tired of support calls to repair my applications after some other poorly Inno-packed app has broken it through improper use.  ClickOnce isn't very practical for VB6 programs.  WiX is quite user-hostile and not the most practical suggestion for VB6 developers.  There are commercial tools which might have been suggested, but I don't think the alternatives listed above are good choices.

Comment: Fair enough. I based my "obsolete" statement on it not being listed anywhere on the Microsoft websites. The tools I mentioned may have slightly steeper learning curves but I've used and can recommend them. I've not used any other commercial tools since I moved away from VSI after many a broken Windows Installer database. I guess we have different experiances :)

Comment: Well I agree that Microsoft has pulled the downloads.  But all of VS 6.0 is "obsolete" in the sense of having little to no support and having been succeeded by later versions.