# How to install "Visual Studio Installer"?

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I adopted an old VB6 program and now need to do few code changes, I am being have Visual Studio 6.0 and service package 6 installed, When I opened the solution file I got an error message "The application for 'xxx.wip' is not installed", so I guess this could be caused by that I missed the Visual Studio Installer.

Then I found out a "Visual Studio Installer 2" on internet, after having downloaded, the file size is around 8.52 MB and it was a Win32 Cabinet Self-Extractor, I double-clicked it and exacted to a place but I got a "VSI2.cab" file.

So there have NO any install executable file after exaction, my question is how I can install Visual Studio Installer I downloaded? how Visual Studio 6.0 aware it and will able to open ".SLN" file without errors, I need copy it to specific folder by handy or even I get wrong download? if so please share the link to me.

Comment: I do not know how complicated your installation is, but perhaps you can migrate it to an other one? I can heartily recommend Inno Setup. I even use that now for my VB.Net programs, it blows the VS installers out of the water.

Comment: Thanks, but in the past, the MSI file was distributed by Visual Studio Installer. so I probably still find a way to use Visual Studio Installer do it.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10362587/issue-about-please-make-sure-the-application-for-the-project-wip-is-installe

Comment: Thank you, I think Not really same question, the question posted here is focusing how I can install “Visual Studio Installer”?

Comment: The question Morten Frederiksen refers to also recommends to switch to a different installer. Give it a try!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio Installer (the real one) is no longer available from Microsoft and VSI2.cab appears to be just part of the VSI installer package.

I have a copy that is [temporarily available for download](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/2931731/Visual%20Installer.zip) (Assuming you agree to all the original conditions from Microsoft that I can't remember here) but I still recommend [using something that's built this century, maybe even this decade](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10380864/588306) :)

Comment: Note that this doesn't seem to install on Windows 7, but you may have more luck.

Comment: Installed and works fine here on several Win7 and Vista machines.

Comment: I think my setup is corrupt though.